# Calling function in alert in Joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla3.0

I am facing an problem. I have a module `mod_vodbalance`. I have created a function `balanceDeduct` in that module. Also i have created a page with `buyNow` button. When I click on `buyNow` button, it shows an `comfirm` with `ok` and `cancel`. I want to call that function `balanceDeduct` when user click on `ok` button and proceed to another page. The Code I am using is this:

```
function deductBalance()
{
    $db        = JFactory::getDBO();
    $result    = null;

    $user    = JFactory::getUser();
    if ($user->guest) {
        return false;
    }

    $query = 'SELECT credit' .
             ' FROM #__vodes_credits' .
             ' WHERE userid = ' . (int) $user->id;
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadResult();

    $result_final=$result-10;

    $query = 'update #__vodes_credits SET credit='.$result_final.
             ' WHERE userid = ' . (int) $user->id;
    $db->setQuery($query);

    $result = $db->loadResult();
    if ($db->getErrorNum()) {
        JError::raiseWarning( 500, $db->stderr() );
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I want to call this function on comfirm box. Please help me to sought it out.